# What happened to the Shinigami Zellogi?

Tags: death-note

In the ninth episode of Death Note, a Shinigami, Zellogi, decides to "check out on Ryuk":

[image]

A conversation with another group of Shinigami goes like this:

> -Who'd want Ryuk as a pet? He's not even cute.
>
> -Haha, you're right.
>
> -So, what kind of human is it? Male or female?
>
> -Who knows. I wonder.
>
> -I'll find out myself.

I imagined that he would go to the human world and make some appearance there, but as far as I know, he doesn't. What happened to him? What did he do?

Comment: Technically the Shinigami don't need to enter the human world to see what's going on, they can see into the Human World using their gate and that's how they can find the names of people to kill, we see this with the Shinigami that sacrificed himself to save Misa as he was watching Misa though the gate, ofcause this doesn't fully answer your question

Answer (score 4):

[Zellogi](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Zellogi) was only seen in that one scene and wasn't mentioned after. It is safe to say that he didn't really enter the human world and just checked on Light through one of the many orbs Shinigami use to check on the human world. Such an orb can be seen when Gelus was watching Misa in chapter 27.

[image: enter image description here!]

From the Wikia article on [Human World](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Human_world):

> Shinigami however can travel to the Human World, and watch Humans by using large spherical orbs found throughout the Shinigami Realm...